# Tkinter Frame Row compressed

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to build a laundry tracker app using tkinter that helps me keep count when i press a button and I also added the option of adding other items optionally. I finally figured out how to add a button on the right row and column but after I made it ran, the 2nd row is suddenly compressed. I haven't touched the row and column properties of the frame since the beginning, it just became that way after I added a new functionality. What did I do wrong here?

```
import customtkinter as ctk 
import tkinter as tk 
import pyglet as pg 


pg.font.add_file("Inter-Black.ttf")
row = 0
class GUI:
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        
        self.btns = [{"name":"shirt", "num" : 0},{"name":"pants", "num" : 0},{"name":"uniform", "num" : 0}]
        self.ref = []
        self.root = ctk.CTk()
        

        self.root.title("Laundry App V.1")

        self.root.geometry("700x500")

        self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight =1 )
        self.root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.root.rowconfigure(1, weight = 2)

        self.frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.root)
        self.frame.grid(row = 1, sticky="nswe")

        self.frame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.frame.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)

        self.frame.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.frame.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)

        self.entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self.root, 
                    width = 250,
                    placeholder_text= "Enter new item",
                    placeholder_text_color= "grey",
                    )
        self.entry.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 1)
        self.entry.bind("<KeyPress>", self.check)

        self.add_new()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def add_new(self):
        global row
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(self.btns)):
            if count %2 == 0:
                row +=1
            col= self.get_pos(i)
            ctk.CTkButton(self.frame, 
            text= f"{self.btns[i]['name'].upper()} : {self.btns[i]['num']}", 
            font = ("inter black", 30)
            ).grid(row = row, column = col, sticky = "nswe")
            count += 1
            
    
    def get_pos(self, i):
        
        
        if i == 0 or i%2 == 0:
            col = 0
        else:
            col = 1 
        
        return col
    
    def check(self, event):
        i = 3
        if event.keycode == 13:
            self.new = self.entry.get()
            
            self.add_btn(self.new, i, self.btns)
            

    def add_btn(self, n, i, d):
        global row
        d.append({"name":str(n), "num":0})
        col = self.get_pos(i)

        ctk.CTkButton(self.frame, 
                    text= f"{self.btns[i]['name'].upper()} : {self.btns[i]['num']}", 
                    font = ("inter black", 30)
                    ).grid(row = row, column = col, sticky = "nswe")

    def add_quant(self, n):
        pass

GUI()
```

Comment: i think it has to do with the line count % 2, if i remove it, the format goes back to normal. I dont really know why

Comment: If you print out `row` and `col` inside `add_new`, you will find that you put those buttons starting from row 1. So the last button will be put in row 2.  However you have just configured `weight=1` for rows 0 and 1, so the last button will not be expanded vertically.